# what is the output of the node in c? im confused

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

i would like to know what will be the data or what will happen in the node when i do this:

```
for example: (this are only snippets of scenario)

typedef struct node_tag{
    int data;
    struct node_tag* next;
}NODE;

char y = ')';
NODE *x = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

x->data = y;
x->next = NULL;

NODE *node = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

// i know that the syntax is not correct but please answer my question

node->data = x->data; //is the data in node will be the same as the data in x?
node->next = NULL;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You can simply try what happens. Do you have any specific concerns? Regarding the question in the code snippet: Yes, if you assign value of one variable to another variable, they hold same value. Besides that, you will have 2 nodes in a linked list.

Comment: to answer your question directly, nothing will happen.  That code won't output anything because the code isn't complete.  Code snippets don't really take the place of complete runnable examples.  Putting your question in the terms of a runnable example is not a waste of time - on the contrary, you'll learn much faster if you hold yourself rigorously to the principle of reproducible examples of behavior.

Comment: @DanielFarrell but the data in node will be the same as the data in x, right? that's what I want to clarify

Comment: Yes, that is what an assignment `=` does. That's not different from `var_a = var_b;` What makes you doubt about it?

Answer (score 0):

yes the value **data** in **node** will be the same as the **data** in **x** as you said , why didn't
you test it, just write before the end of the `main`, write these 2 lines to make sure and don't forget to include `<stdio.h>` haeder file:

```
printf("node date : %d\n", node->data);
printf("x date : %d\n", x->data);
```

and here is the output :

```
node date : 41
x date : 41
```

notice that the value *41* is just the [ASCII representation](https://www.asciitable.com/) of the char `)`

the line `node->data = x->data;` is equivalent to saying `(*node).data = (*x).data;` ,
which is just referring to the place of variable `data` and assigning its place to another place in the memory called also `data` but belongs to another instance of that struct.

also you have a small problem in line `x->data = y;` , this should give you warning as lValue is `int` while the rValue is `char` and here is the warning that my compiler gives me:

> Clang-Tidy: 'signed char' to 'int' conversion; consider casting to 'unsigned char' first

so you should cast this value , so do `x->data = (int)y;` not `x->data = y;`

and one last thing , you should always check for the value returned from `malloc` function as it may return `NULL` if it couldn't allocate that memory for you in the heap , so it's a good practice to `if(node != NULL && x != NULL) { . . .}`

and here is the full code to test it:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_tag{
    int data;
    struct node_tag* next;
}NODE;

int main() {
    char y = ')';

    NODE *x = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    NODE *node = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    /*always check if malloc could allocate tha memory for you*/
    if(x != NULL && node != NULL)
    {
        //initialization
        x->data = (int)y;
        x->next = NULL;
        node->next = NULL;

        // test 1
        node->data = x->data;
        printf("node date test(1) : %d\n", node->data);
        printf("x date test(1) : %d\n", x->data);

        //test 2
        x->data = 25;
        (*node).data = (*x).data;;
        printf("node date test(2) : %d\n", node->data);
        printf("x date test(2) : %d\n", x->data);

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the output:

```
node date test(1) : 41
x date test(1) : 41
node date test(2) : 25
x date test(2) : 25
```